# Search function returns the same regardless of item present in the binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>

struct tree_node
{
    tree_node *left;
    tree_node *right;
    int data;
    char r;
} ;
class bst
{
    tree_node *root;
    public:
    bst()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    int isempty()
    {
        return(root==NULL);
    }
    void insert(int item);
    void inordertrav();
    void inorder(tree_node *);
    void postordertrav();
    void postorder(tree_node *);
    void preordertrav();
    void preorder(tree_node *);
    int search(tree_node * ,int);
};
void bst::insert(int item)
{
    tree_node *p=new tree_node;
    tree_node *previous;
    p->data=item;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;
    previous=NULL;
    if(isempty())
        root=p;
    else
    {
        tree_node *current;
        current=root;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            previous=current;
            if(item<current->data)
                current=current->left;
            else
                current=current->right;
        }
        if(item<previous->data)
            previous->left=p;
        else
            previous->right=p;
    }
}

int bst::search(tree_node* root,int data) {
    int r;
    if(root == NULL) {
       //   r='f';
        return 0;
    }
    else if (root != NULL){
    if(root->data == data) {
       //   r='t';
        return 1;
    }
    }
    else if(data <= root->data) {
          return search(root->left,data);
    }
    else {
          return search(root->right,data);
    }

}
void main()
{
    int digit;
    bst b;
    tree_node *root;
    /*b.insert(52);
    b.insert(25);
    b.insert(50);
    b.insert(15);
    b.insert(40);
    b.insert(45);
    b.insert(20); */
    cout<<"insert the nodes in the BT";
    cout<<"enter integer: to quit enter 0";
    cin>>digit;
    while (digit!=0)
    {
        b.insert(digit);
        cin>>digit;
    }
         cout<<"inorder"<<endl;
    b.inordertrav();
    cout<<endl<<"postorder"<<endl;
    b.postordertrav();
    cout<<endl<<"preorder"<<endl;
    b.preordertrav();
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter number be searched\n";
    cin>>number;
    //If number is found, print "FOUND"
    int c;
    c=b.search(root,number);
    cout<<"returned value"<<c;
    if (c==1) cout<<"Found\n";
    else cout<<"Not Found\n";
    getch();
}
```

The search function is always returning the same value whether it is in the BST or not.
Please help me to figure out the error.
The above code has no compilation error.
All other functions except search function are working fine.
But the search function is not working as required to search whether the element is in the Binary Search tree or not.

Comment: Hi, please correct and format your code. As it is, it is hard to read and understand.

Comment: Look at the first two conditions in `search` and try to find a case when they are both false. I think you have a bracket-placement problem.

Comment: You should read [this excellent blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging small programs such as this one, and apply the techniques explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code invoke UB.

```
tree_node *root;
...
c=b.search(root,number);  // root is uninitialized
```

To solve this add a new function:

```
class bst
{
    ...
    int search(tree_node * ,int);
    int search(int v) {
        return search(root, v);
    }
};
```

Also in `bst::search` function:

```
else //if (root != NULL){  Comment this condition
if(root->data == data) {
   //   r='t';
    return 1;
}
//} Comment this line
```

This condition is not only redundant but also make some code flow paths return without value.

Comment: Still the program is not giving required output.